# Squares outside every character in TextMesh Pro

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm getting this bug that when I'm far from the text it starts showing squares all around the each character of the text. This is probably because of the font (I'm using Gidolinya https://www.1001fonts.com/gidolinya-font.html), I tried switching to Open Sans and this issue stops. Is there any way to fix this without changing the font?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this issue happens when you have an incorrect ratio of ***Sampling Point Size** to **Padding***.

Try keeping that around 10%.

More instructions here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/textmeshpro-smudgy-in-game.708896/#post-4737197

Answer (score 0):

Additional info for Menioh's answer:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/text-mesh-pro-box-around-text-unwanted-effect-bug.665647/

Keeping the ratio around 10% does the job but reducing Perspective Filter helps too:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is just a workaround but for me it was solved setting *Sharpness* to 1 in SDF Material / *Debug Settings*